Copy website files to another site, keeping permissions, and exclude some files
I have two websites, will have more, the same code except config, and some other files. Two brands of same project. Will have more sites - testing site for example. Also, I need to update DB structure of sites, with file Upd55.sql for example.
Code I use to copy files, from current folder: (important to keep permissions)
cp -p -R -v ./ ../web.site.pro/

I need to exclude /config/ .htaccess and some more files.

cp is not suitable for this. Here is how I do task with rsync:
leonid@leonid-asus:~/Instalator$ cat InstallSites.exclude
/u/*
/config/db.config.inc.php
/site.compiled/*
/logs/*
/invoices/*
/.htaccess

leonid@leonid-asus:~/Instalator$ cat InstallSites.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

declare -A config=()
config[exclude]="/home/leonid/Instalator/InstallSites.exclude"
config[logfile1]="/home/leonid/Instalator/InstallSites.log"
config[logfile2]="/home/leonid/Instalator/InstallSites2.log"
config[source]="/home/leonid/Web/site/"
config[destination1]="/home/leonid/Instalator/RSyncTest/"
config[destination2]="/home/leonid/Instalator/RSyncTest2/"

rsync --stats --recursive --links --perms --owner --group --exclude-from="${config[exclude]}" --log-file="${config[logfile1]}" "${config[source]}" "${config[destination1]}"
rsync --stats --recursive --links --perms --owner --group --exclude-from="${config[exclude]}" --log-file="${config[logfile2]}" "${config[source]}" "${config[destination2]}"

Here is how to copy to remote host:
leonid@leonid-asus:~/Instalator$ cat InstallTesting.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

declare -A config=()
config[exclude]="/home/leonid/Instalator/InstallSites.exclude"
config[logfile3]="/home/leonid/Instalator/InstallSites3.log"
config[source]="/home/leonid/Web/site/"
config[destination1]="root@site.ru:/root/RSyncTest/"

rsync --progress --stats --recursive --links --perms --owner --group --chown="user:www-data" --exclude-from="${config[exclude]}" --log-file="${config[logfile3]}" "${config[source]}" "${config[destination1]}"

